# How to grease a parchment paper for SugarVeil?

Tags: baking, sugar

How can I  grease a parchment paper, for making SugarVeil? Because I want to do my own SugarVeil design. I already tried it with butter for greasing, but after lace is dry, it stick on the parchment paper & can't roll out.

Comment: Is this like what you're doing? https://cakejournal.com/tutorials/using-sugarveil-icing/

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use parchment paper, you'll need to use Crisco, not butter. The downside of Crisco is you may end up with a small amount of undesired flavor/texture on your SugarVeil.

Alternatively, you can purchase [SugarVeil Mats](http://amzn.to/2iW5VDB), which are basically silicon mats with imprints of various designs on them.